# Typsetting Furigana in LaTeX (AUTOMATICALLY)

Tags: languages, japanese

Is it possible to use LaTeX to display furigana over kanji, without having to manually write the furigana for large sections of text similar to the \xpinyin package?[image]

```
\subsection{Transcription - Market}

\xpinyin*{我家附近有一个菜市场。我经常去那里买水果，蔬菜，还有肉。那么今天我就带你们去，逛逛我们中国的菜市场。好啦，我们走吧。好啦！现在我们到了水果摊。这是我经常过来买的一家。我们现在去看一下。嗨，老板娘。你好。我来买一点水果。}\\\\\xpinyin*{好啊！买点什么水果了?}\\\\\xpinyin*{看一下啊！这个是什么啊？}\\\\\xpinyin*{那个是红提}\\\\\xpinyin*{甜不甜？}\\\\\xpinyin*{甜!}\\\\\xpinyin*{可以试一下吗？}\\\\\xpinyin*{可以可以}\\\\\xpinyin*{好甜啊。这个多少钱一斤}\\\\\xpinyin*{这个就是五}\\\\\xpinyin*{十五块钱一斤啊}\\\\\xpinyin*{对}\\\\\xpinyin*{那这种的呢}\\\\\xpinyin*{这种就十二}\\\\\xpinyin*{这个要贵一点啊？}\\\\\xpinyin*{这个要贵一点，这个红提贵一点，这个正宗新疆那边过来的。}\\\\\xpinyin*{新疆过来的！那你给我称。。。称一斤吧}\\\\\xpinyin*{这个我就。。。我就拿着吧! 就丢这里， 就丢那旁边! 一斤。 不知道又没有那么准哈。切这里}\\\\\xpinyin*{可以啊}\\\\\xpinyin*{会不会多？这串跟这串。}\\\\\xpinyin*{没事}\\\\\xpinyin*{差一点点一斤}\\\\\xpinyin*{可以，可以}\\\\\xpinyin*{这个多少钱? 这里。}\\\\\xpinyin*{这里，收十四块好了}\\\\\xpinyin*{十四块十八？给我便宜了！老板娘！老板娘非常地热情，所以我很喜欢来这里买的。那，这样子你带我们的学生认识一下你们的水果，好不好？}
```

Comment: afaik that is not possible. How is LaTeX supposed to know which reading to apply?

Comment: Unlike Korean or Chinese, mapping from hanja/hanzi/kanji to kana looks unusually complex to be feasible in an easy manner, let alone using TeX